# C# - ResXResourceReader initialized with embedded ResX - stream results in "ResX-File: The root element doesn't exist, can't be analyzed" exception

Tags: c#, .net, resx

Basically, I want to read a value **and** a comment from any ResX file specified.

Therefore im getting all embedded resources with

```
string[] allResourceFileNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

and searching for the specific given one with something like:

```
string embeddedResourceName = allResourceFileNames.SingleOrDefault(resourceFileName => resourceFileName.Contains("MenuResources"));
```

This delivers this string (= Complete namespace): 
*Project.Folder.Subfolder.MenuResources.resources*

Now I create a Stream with:

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedResourceName );
```

The created stream is not null.

Now I create a new ResXResourceReader (which I need to easily access the comments in the ResX files) with the returned stream:

```
        using (var resourceReader = new ResXResourceReader(stream)
        {
            UseResXDataNodes = true
        })
        {
            IDictionaryEnumerator dictionary = resourceReader.GetEnumerator();
        }
```

But when I access dictionary, I always get the exception: **"ResX-File: The root element doesn't exist, can't be analyzed"** and I have no idea why.
I use the standard Microsoft ResX Schema with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< root\ >
.....
< /root >
```

Anyone knows what is wrong here? Why can't the stream be read correctly? It seems to me, that the MS ResX Schema isn't supported or wathever...

Comment: It simply is not data in the resx format.  It used to be, but not anymore after Resgen.exe turned it into binary data that is as compact as possible.  Use either ResourceReader or ResourceManager.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I see that I misunterstood the issue.